# sequelize is not including user on model.create

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Sequlelize is not returning the associated user when creating a post. here is the router .

I've referred to the documentation as well.

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/associations.html#creating-with-associations

```
 createPost: async (req: any, res: Response) => {
    const postData = {
      title: req.body.title,
      postContent: req.body.postContent,
      authorId: req.session.user.id
    };
    await models.Post.create(postData, {
      include: [{ model: models.User, as: "author" }]
    })
      .then(post => {
        res.status(200).send({
          message: "post created",
          post: post
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(401).send({
          message: `Something went wrong`,
          error: err
        });
      });
    console.log(req.body);
  }
```

I'm not sure why this is not working, because this route gets the post with the respective user, with the username

```
  getPosts: async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    await models.Post.findAll({
      include: [
        { model: models.User, as: "author", attributes: ["username"] },
        { model: models.Likes }
      ],
      order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
      limit: 6
    }).then(posts => {
      res.json(posts);
    });
  },
```

here is the model for Post and User.

**User.js**

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    var User = sequelize.define("User", {
        username: DataTypes.STRING,
        password: DataTypes.STRING,
        email: DataTypes.STRING,
        forget_password: DataTypes.STRING
    });
    User.associate = function (models) {
        User.hasMany(models.Post, {
            foreignKey: "authorId",
            as: "author",
            onDelete: "CASCADE"
        });
    };
    return User;
};
```

**Post.js**

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    var Post = sequelize.define("Post", {
        title: DataTypes.STRING,
        postContent: DataTypes.STRING,
        liked: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: false
        },
        likeCounts: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0
        },
        authorId: DataTypes.INTEGER
    });
    Post.associate = function (models) {
        Post.belongsTo(models.User, {
            as: "author",
            foreignKey: "authorId",
            onDelete: "CASCADE"
        });
        Post.hasMany(models.Likes, {
            foreignKey: "resourceId",
            timestamps: false,
            onDelete: "CASCADE",
            scope: {
                type: "article"
            }
        });
    };
    return Post;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives me the result i want, so this will work.

```
await models.Post.create(postData)
  .then(post => {
    models.Post.findOne({
      where: {
        id: post.id
      },
      include: [
        { model: models.User, as: "author", attributes: ["username"] },
        { model: models.Likes }
      ]
    }).then(newPost => {
      res.status(200).send({
        message: "post created",
        post: newPost
      });
    });
  })
```